# How to add zero to single digit in a string

Tags: vbscript, qtp, hp-uft

I need to to append zero in my below string whenever I get date with single digit without changing Quantity digit (*below string is system generated in my application not created by user*),

> Data Added Quantity:1 on Dec **9** 2015 modified on Jun **7** 2016

I need to change this string just like below,

> Data Added Quantity:125 on Dec **09** 2015 modified on Jun **07** 2016

So far I have tried the below regular expression, but not getting desired output.

```
str = "Data Added Quantity:1 on Dec 9 2015 modified on Jun 7 2016"
Set oReg = New RegExp
oReg.Pattern = "\s\d{1}\s"
Set obj = oReg.Execute(str)
For i = 0 To obj.Count-1
  mD = obj.Item(i).Value
  oReg.Replace(str, "0" & mD)
Next
```

How we can achieve this using VBScript?

Comment: Format the dates correctly before inserting them into the string.

Comment: Demonstrate how you are building the string and what you have already tried; it will be a lot simpler to help you go right if we can see where you went wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you adjust the pattern a little and set the `Global` option to `True` you can simply use the `Replace` method. No need to `Excecute` and loop.

```
Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern = "\s(\d)\s"
re.Global  = True

str = re.Replace(str, " 0$1 ")
```

`\d` without a modifier already matches exactly one digit, so `\d{1}` is redundant. The parentheses around the `\d` define a capturing group that allows you to use the matched substring in the replacement (`$1`).